# Amazon Rekognition Text detection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

I've been unable to find the URL to make the API call for AWS Rekognition for text detection. I found [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_Reference.html) documentation for headers and parameters to be sent, but there is no Base URL mentioned in the post.

Is it available somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) to access services.

Here is an example using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws rekognition detect-text --image 'S3Object={Bucket=my-bucket,Name=foo.jpg}'
```

You can make similar calls using an SDK for your favourite programming language.